# Get current row color in TemplateField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, gridview

I have a situation where I need to know the current color of an alternating row in a TemplateField of a GridView.

UPDATED:

How do I retrieve this Color value in a `<%# ??? %>`.

(Or an workaround where I get the row number).

Comment: It is unclear as to where (i.e., in what eventhandler and what stage of the gridview databinding process) you wish to retrieve the said color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this function in your codebehind page (or in a  section in your .aspx page):

```
protected string GetColor(object container)
        {
            int ordinal = 0;
            try
            {
                ordinal = int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(container, "DataItemIndex").ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ordinal = int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(container, "ItemIndex").ToString());
            }
            return (ordinal % 2) == 0 ? "Row" : "Alternate Row";
        }
```

Then in your markup, you'd call it like so:

```
<%# GetOrdinal(Container) %>
```

(Note the uppercase "Container").

Answer (score 1):

To get the colors from inside of a <% %> tag in the template field itself, you could use this code...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate ? ((GridView)((GridViewRow)Container).Parent.Parent).AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor : ((GridView)((GridViewRow)Container).Parent.Parent).RowStyle.BackColor%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can also do this in the RowDataBound event of the GridView.  In the RowDataBound command, you can query the e.Row.RowState to find out what type of row you are on.  Values include DataControlRowState.Alternate and DataControlRowState.Normal.  You can use the sender to grab the color based on that row type...

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    // set first cell in the row to color just for demonstration purpose.
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ((GridView)sender).AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:help;");
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        { 
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {                
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='orange'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#E56E94'");
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#E56E94");                
           }           
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='orange'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='gray'");
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");                
            }
            //e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");
            //e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");
            //e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");
            //e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");
            //e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.FromName("gray");
            //e.Row.BorderWidth = 2;
            //e.Row.BorderColor = Color.FromName("#43C6DB");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a weird work-around, but you could always check to see if the row you are checking for is an odd or even numbered row. If it is an even number, it is likely using the color set up in the AlternatingRow template. If it is even, it should be using the regular Row template.

Answer (score 0):

How does the GridView change colour - every other row, or in chunks of X? Or is it set in some more "random" fashion?

If it's every other row, you can simply check if the row is a "normal" row or an "alternating" row.

I can't remember how it's written exactly, and I only found this VB example, but it might be of some help:

```
If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal Then
 //do stuff
ElseIf e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Alternate Then
 //do other stuff
```

Where e is the GridView object. This doesn't check the actual colour of the row though. I suppose you should be able to do something like:

```
if(System.Drawing.Color.Red == e.Row.BackColor)
```

If you can, please be more detailed as to how the colour is set on each row.

Comment: <RowStyle BackColor="#E9CE90"></RowStyle>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F6EED5"></AlternatingRowStyle>

Comment: Then you don't really need to know the colour, only the type of the row (Normal, Alaternating). If it's normal, you know the colour is #E9CE90, else it's #F6EED5. My VB example should help you on your way.

Comment: Typical info that's good to have in the question from the start. Never mind, I think Scott just gave you what you need.